# Can I use a JS variable in this case and how?

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($a[i want to put the js var here]); ?>;
```

I'll appreciate any quick answer to this.
Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**. You can render server side code into you client side code but not the other way around.

The php runs on the server and has been executed before your client does anything.

If you post your JavaScript variable back to the server you would be able to process it again.